# Autocomplete generates loss-of-focus event on selection

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I gather this must be a very common use case: user types into a textbox and lookups are made against a database displaying choices.  when the user is done (leaves the textbox), a determination is made as to whether the value entered was picked from the list (and therefore already exists in the database) and if it was nothing is done, otherwise the value entered is inserted into the database (since it's new).

problem is, clicking on the list of choices causes a /focusout/ which means that I don't know whether the user is leaving the textbox because he's done, or because he's choosing a value.  therefore I don't have a good way of knowing when I should make my database insertion.  If he types two characters and finds a match, clicking on the list of items will cause an insertion of the two characters.

I've opened [a bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7336) about it and found various others with similar problems but no resolution.

I can't think of a way around this problem.  I'm using version 1.8.10 of jquery-ui. can anyone help?

Comment: Can't you check whether the mouse is over the list of choices prior to inserting? [Something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846396/jquery-is-mouse-over-element).

Comment: Do you really need to insert it right after typing? Can't it be done when the page is submitted?

Comment: @ariel: That's a better idea :)

Comment: think Web 2.0 - lots of stuff happens on your page without ever refreshing.  it's the whole poing of Ajax

Comment: as for checking for mouse position before insertion, it's not sufficient.  you need to know when the user is done with his choice of text, and that happens when he leaves the text box.  he may chose something from the list, change it and decide that's what he wants

Comment: oh yeah.  I have to wait some eternity before I can answer my own question.  I don't get the logic of that, but, whatever! LoL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after much wailing and gnashing of teeth, here's the answer:

1. don't bother with the /select/ event of the autocomplete (it's completely useless when issued after a change (for the purpose of this exercise))
2. set a flag when the list gets clicked on.  use the /mousedown/ instead of /focus/ since this happens before the /blur/ of the textbox
3. hook the database insertion code on the /change/ event of the text box, instead of the /blur/ (better semantics)
4. implement a semaphore check on the change event
5. implement a database existence check if semaphore check succeeds
6. insert into database!

```
    // step 2
    $(".ui-autocomplete").mousedown(function() { ListExit = true; })

    // step 3
    $("#MyTextBox").change(function() {

        // step 4
       if (ListExist) {
          ListExit = false;
          return;
       }

       // step 5
       $.ajax({
           url: "@Url.Action("List", "MyController")",
           data: {term: $(this).val()},
           success: function(ls) {
               if (ls.length > 0) return;
               // step 6: do database insertion
           }
       });
    });
```

Comment: (embarrasingly) HERE'S A MUCH BETTER SOLUTION: use the `autocompletechange` event e.g. $("#").autocomplete({change: function() {}});

it's documented, I just didn't understand the docs.  duh!

Answer (score 1):

The loss of focus is only momentary, you can start a timeout to delay submitting and cancel it if the field regains focus. The following example waits for 0.5 seconds before processing:

```
function BindTimeout($elem){
    $elem.data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
        $elem.removeData('timer');

        if($elem.hasClass('autocomplete-open')){
            BindTimeout($elem);
        } else {
            // Do whatever you need to do with the field value
        }
    }, 1000));
}

$('input').bind({
    focus: function(){
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
    },
    blur: function(){
        BindTimeout($(this));
    },
    autocompleteopen: function(){
        $(this).addClass('autocomplete-open');
    },
    autocompleteclose: function(){
        $(this).removeClass('autocomplete-open');
    }
});
```

**Edit:** When the focus is lost, it keeps checking wether the suggestion box is still open.

Comment: sure.  that'll only work if the user hangs out over the list box for 1/2 second.  if he moves the mouse and gets a phone call you're in trouble

Comment: You can give this a try, I edited my code. The point is, it can be done, but that doesn't mean you should. :) If there is a better place to save your data (like on submit as others suggested), you might be better off doing that.

Comment: I hear you.  It's not part of my design to have a submission button... think of embedded managers where you get to edit a list of things that belong to something else... you need to do your thing without leaving the page

Comment: one way to solve the problem would be to make the decision about whether the `blur` is happening because the user is done and data should be written to the database, or because he's picking something from the list (and isn't really leaving at all).  if the eventObject passed to the `blur` or `focusout` handlers contained a reference to the element that is to receive the focus I could make that decision.  it doesn't but maybe there's some other way to make that determination...